# knitr and SQL query

Tags: sql, r, knitr

I am having difficulty querying a SQL database from a knitr chunk. I can establish a connection and the query works in an R session but hangs indefinitely when knitting from RStudio.

---

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "XXXXX XXXXXXXXX"
date: "Monday, April 27, 2015"
output: html_document
---

TEST TEST

```{r}

library(RJDBC)

jd<-JDBC(driverClass = "com.osisoft.jdbc.Driver",classPath = "C://Program Files (x86)//PIPC//JDBC//PIJDBCDriver.jar")

piDB<-dbConnect(drv = jd,"jdbc:pisql://XX.XXX.XX.XX/Data Source=XXX;Integrated Security=SSPI")

sql1<-"SELECT * FROM pipoints"

sql.dat <- dbGetQuery(piDB, sql1)

dbDisconnect(piDB)

print('Success')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a different connection driver, try ODBC.

RODBC works fine with knitr in RStudio:

````
```{r}
library(RODBC)
myconn = odbcConnect('myServer')
myquery = paste0("")                      #add some query
data = sqlQuery(myconn, myquery)
head(data)
```
````

Comment: On a side note, in many cases one may use DSN-less connection, i.e. without setting up ODBC entry. Perhaps, [this might help](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Troubleshooting/KB/3234OSI8).

Answer (score 0):

With RStudio v1.0 you can now use sql chunks directly from your RMarkdown or RNotebook. I use the odbc package for this. I like this because it avoids hard-coding login details into your projects while still creating projects that run end-to-end without user input.

An RMarkdown example below:

````
```{r}
# Unfortunately, odbc is not on CRAN yet
# So we will need devtools
# install.packages(devtools)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/odbc")

# Get connection info from the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator using the name you set manually. 
# If you don't know what this is, just search in the windows start menu for     "ODBC Data Source Administrator"
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'MyDataWarehouse')
```

```{sql connection = con, output.var = result}
-- This is sql code, comments need to be marked accordingly
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE LIMIT 200;
```

```{R}
# And the result is available in the next chunk!
result
```
````